# How do I open NetBeans projects, created in Windows 7, in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans, windows-7, ide

I saved all of my NetBeans projects onto a folder in my dropbox account on windows, but now when I tried to open one in NetBeans on Ubuntu (14.04) nothing happens, and I get an error message. I've check the JDK is the same, so I'm not sure what else could be the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

The whole error message is displayed below:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.CancelAbort starting from ModuleCL@5ba607b4[org.netbeans.modules.java.source] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@531b49df[org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@71ffd9f1[org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup], ModuleCL@26c5920f[org.netbeans.modules.java.lexer], ModuleCL@503ca641[org.netbeans.modules.java.platform], ModuleCL@543d97af[org.openide.text], ModuleCL@419fb314[org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.project], ModuleCL@1c04fc63[org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib], ModuleCL@71b87cd4[org.netbeans.modules.projectuiapi], ModuleCL@562390c0[org.netbeans.api.java], ModuleCL@1533a69e[org.openide.windows], ModuleCL@5d171820[org.openide.dialogs], ...26 more]
>       at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>   Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/util/CancelAbort
>       at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParserFactory.createParser(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParserFactory.createParser(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.findParser(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.parseWhenScanFinished(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.runWhenScanFinished(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.MainClassUpdater.addFileChangeListener(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.MainClassUpdater.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProject$ProjectOpenedHookImpl.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.UILookupMergerSupport$OpenHookImpl.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
>   [catch] at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.notifyOpened(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.doOpenProject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.doOpen(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.access$2000(Unknown Source)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: What version of NetBeans on Windows? on Ubuntu? What version of JDK?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Ubuntu Software Centre version I had installed was a version out of date. I got the new 8.0 version direct from NetBeans and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the perfect solution, it's just a workaround. If it's a simple project you could erase the nbproject folder and create a new project with existing sources with that netbeans will re-create the project files.